# Cypress command that return values from DOM

Tags: cypress

In my DOM i have an input and a div, and i want to get the value of both in one command.

Here is an HTML exemple

```
<div id="myDiv">Content of the div</div>
<input id="myInput" value="2000" />
```

Here is what i tried for my command

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getDomValues", () => {
        var divValue = cy.get('#myDiv').invoke('text')
        var inputValue = cy.get('#myInput').invoke('val')

        return cy.wrap({
            divValue:divValue,
            inputValue:inputValue
        });
        
});
```

If there is no cy.wrap around my returned object i get this error

> Unhandled rejection CypressError: Cypress detected that you invoked
> one or more cy commands in a custom command but returned a different
> value.

---

And then in my test for now i use it like that

```
cy.getDomValues().then((values)=>{
   console.log(values)
})
```

In my console inside the returned object i have something like that for both values

```
$Chainer {userInvocationStack: "    at Context.eval (http://localhost:8888/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/support/index.js:181:24)", specWindow: Window, chainerId: "chainer4419", firstCall: false, useInitialStack: false}
```

Do you have any idea how i could have a result like that ?

```
{
   divValue:"Content of the div",
   inputValue:"2000"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the values with `.then()`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("getDomValues", () => {
  cy.get('#myDiv').invoke('text').then(divValue => {
    cy.get('#myInput').invoke('val').then(inputValue => {

      // no need to wrap, Cypress does it for you
      return {
        divValue,       // short form if attribute name === variable name
        inputValue
      }
});
```

The error you received was because you were returning `Chainers` instead of values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.as()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as) to assign an alias for later use.

```
cy.get('#myDiv').invoke('text').as('divValue')
cy.get('##myInput').invoke('val').as('inputValue')
```

Then use these values later separately like -

```
cy.get('@divValue').then(divValue => {
  //Do something with div value
})

cy.get('@inputValue').then(inputValue => {
  //Do something with input value
})
```

OR, use these values later together like -

```
cy.get('@divValue').then(divValue => {
    cy.get('@inputValue').then(inputValue => {
        //Do something with div value
        //Do something with input value
    })
})
```